# ASP.NET MVC 2 Controllers to Model Associations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, controller

In my model I have relationships like this:

```
[Person]
 PersonId (PK)
 ...

[Orders]
 OrderId (PK)
 PersonId (FK to Person.PersonId)
 ...
```

A person can have multiple orders.

I generated PersonController with Create/Details/List/Edit views. I want to be able to manipulate Orders also, but within the context of a Person. In other words, I'd like the workflow to be

- User browses a list of people (/Persons)
- User selects 'View Orders' link next to a specific Person (/Persons/4/Orders/)
- User sees a list of orders with Create/Details/Edit as well (/Persons/4/Orders/Edit/38)

Is this the right way to set up my controllers/routes?
Should I just access orders at routes like (/Orders/Edit/38) instead?

Right now I have:

PersonController
OrderController

Should I create a PersonOrderController or can I achieve what I want using only the two controllers I already have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use just the two Controllers you already have.  It is a judgment call however.  Two different excellent MVC designers might do this two different ways.  Unless you already see a lot of other work for your OrderController, you should start with two controllers.  If OrderController becomes bloated, you can refactor.